# Fastlane App Store build becomes available in Testflight

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, fastlane

I upload my app to testflight like this:

```
upload_to_testflight(
      ipa: "ios/builds/Momo.ipa",
      skip_submission: false,
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: false,
      notify_external_testers: true,
      distribute_external: true,
      reject_build_waiting_for_review: true,
      expire_previous_builds: true,
      groups: [
        "External Testers"
      ],
      changelog: "Perfomance improvements and bug fixes"
    )
```

This is on the `staging` branch and with the scheme `MyAppStaging`.

On the `production` branch the scheme is `MyAppProduction` and the submit code is:

```
upload_to_app_store(
      submit_for_review: true,
      automatic_release: true,
      force: true,
      skip_metadata: true,
      skip_screenshots: true,
      submission_information:"{\"export_compliance_uses_encryption\": false, \"add_id_info_uses_idfa\": false }"
    )
```

We want different schemes for config etc.

But when I upload to App Store from the `production` branch this build will also be available for the testflight users.

How can we disable this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically this is a fundamental problem with TestFlight and how Apple designed that system. TestFlight is for testing the build that goes into the AppStore, aka. the actual production build. AppStoreConnect does not really support having a "test" build and a "production" build, only "build"s.

Comment: Thanks. So we just need to work with it this way i think